# Community Detection OSLOM implementation. How Does OSLOM Algorithm work?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

How does [OSLOM](http://oslom.org) algorithm work? Can anyone please explain it in layman terms. I don't need to understand the entire algorithm, I just need on what criteria does it cluster the nodes?

I've used the OSLOM software available in the website and implemented it on my set of data.
which is of the form

```
node1 node2 weight
```

let the input be

```
0 1 0.2
1 2 0.2
0 3 99
3 4 1.5
```

According to my observation in the output it is clustering the input based on the weight of the edge between each node. the nodes that have the same weight belong to the same module of a community. 
So the output would be

```
#module 1
0 1 2
#module 2
3 4
```

please let me know if i am right?

Please use a small undirected weighted graph to explain.

Comment: Have you looked at the [paper]http://oslom.org/oslom.pdf

Comment: Yes, but that's a little complicated, can you suggest me a easy tutorial or a video lecture on community detection or oslom ?

Comment: I am sure there is no such thing